# Optimizing Squid Proxy latency

Tags: http, proxy, server, squid

I am still learning squid and dont understand how this happens. Right now I have a server, when I ping a website from the server, I can get average ping time of 1ms. However, after making some proxies using Squid and test pinging the same website through the proxies on the same server (using a proxy testing application), the lowest ping time is 98ms (after i changed the dns server, the lowest went down to 94ms). So what is causing the big difference, from 1ms to 90+ms? Are there any ways to optimize the proxies? I am running the squid proxy server and the application on the same server. Any help or input would be greatly appreciated!!

```
    #
# Recommended minimum configuration:
#
auth_param basic program  /cygdrive/c/squid/lib/squid/basic_ncsa_auth /cygdrive/c/squid/etc/squid/pwfile
auth_param basic children 10

# Example rule allowing access from your local networks.
# Adapt to list your (internal) IP networks from where browsing
# should be allowed

acl localnet src 10.0.0.0/8 # RFC1918 possible internal network
acl localnet src 172.16.0.0/12  # RFC1918 possible internal network
acl localnet src 192.168.0.0/16 # RFC1918 possible internal network
acl localnet src fc00::/7       # RFC 4193 local private network range
acl localnet src fe80::/10      # RFC 4291 link-local (directly plugged) machines

acl SSL_ports port 443
acl Safe_ports port 80      # http
acl Safe_ports port 21      # ftp
acl Safe_ports port 443     # https
acl Safe_ports port 70      # gopher
acl Safe_ports port 210     # wais
acl Safe_ports port 1025-65535  # unregistered ports
acl Safe_ports port 280     # http-mgmt
acl Safe_ports port 488     # gss-http
acl Safe_ports port 591     # filemaker
acl Safe_ports port 777     # multiling http
acl CONNECT method CONNECT

acl auth_users proxy_auth REQUIRED

acl authip src 1.1.1.1

http_access allow authip

# Only allow cachemgr access from localhost
http_access allow localhost manager
http_access deny manager
http_access allow auth_users

# Deny requests to certain unsafe ports
http_access deny !Safe_ports

# Deny CONNECT to other than secure SSL ports
http_access deny CONNECT !SSL_ports

# We strongly recommend the following be uncommented to protect innocent
# web applications running on the proxy server who think the only
# one who can access services on "localhost" is a local user
#http_access deny to_localhost

#
# INSERT YOUR OWN RULE(S) HERE TO ALLOW ACCESS FROM YOUR CLIENTS
#

# And finally deny all other access to this proxy
http_access deny all

# Example rule allowing access from your local networks.
# Adapt localnet in the ACL section to list your (internal) IP networks
# from where browsing should be allowed
http_access allow localnet
http_access allow localhost

acl ip1 myip 1.1.1.1

tcp_outgoing_address 1.1.1.1 ip1

tcp_outgoing_address 0.0.0.0 all

http_access allow ip1

# Squid normally listens to port 3128
http_port 2424

# Uncomment the line below to enable disk caching - path format is /cygdrive/<full path to cache folder>, i.e.
cache_dir awin32 d:/squidcachedir/cache 10000 16 256
# memory_cache_mode always
maximum_object_size_in_memory 102400 KB
half_closed_clients off
cache_mem 256 MB
memory_pools off

# Leave coredumps in the first cache dir
coredump_dir /var/cache/squid

# Add any of your own refresh_pattern entries above these.
refresh_pattern ^ftp:       1440    20% 10080
refresh_pattern ^gopher:    1440    0%  1440
refresh_pattern -i (/cgi-bin/|\?) 0 0%  0
refresh_pattern .       0   20% 4320

# cache_peer 23.0.13.5 parent 3128 3130 default no-query

ipcache_size 10240
negative_dns_ttl 5 minutes
positive_dns_ttl 6 hours
dns_nameservers 129.250.35.250 74.82.42.42 208.67.222.222 
cache_replacement_policy heap
cache_swap_low 90
cache_swap_high 95
quick_abort_min 0 KB
quick_abort_max 0 KB
log_icp_queries off
client_db off
buffered_logs on
half_closed_clients off

max_filedescriptors 3200

dns_v4_first on

forwarded_for delete

request_header_access Allow allow all
request_header_access Authorization allow all
request_header_access WWW-Authenticate allow all
request_header_access Proxy-Authorization allow all
request_header_access Proxy-Authenticate allow all
request_header_access Cache-Control allow all
request_header_access Content-Encoding allow all
request_header_access Content-Length allow all
request_header_access Content-Type allow all
request_header_access Date allow all
request_header_access Expires allow all
request_header_access Host allow all
request_header_access If-Modified-Since allow all
request_header_access Last-Modified allow all
request_header_access Location allow all
request_header_access Pragma allow all
request_header_access Accept allow all
request_header_access Accept-Charset allow all
request_header_access Accept-Encoding allow all
request_header_access Accept-Language allow all
request_header_access Content-Language allow all
request_header_access Mime-Version allow all
request_header_access Retry-After allow all
request_header_access Title allow all
request_header_access Connection allow all
request_header_access Proxy-Connection allow all
request_header_access User-Agent allow all
request_header_access Cookie allow all
request_header_access All deny all
```

Comment: did you test with an http request directly to the server?  There are lots of overheads hitting an http server vs pinging (ICMP).  Also any proxy setup is setting up 2 connections, client->proxy and then proxy->server.  Probably the latency comes in the fact squid needs to receive the request from the client before it can know which server to connect to.

Comment: thank you for the reply. i am pinging directly from the proxy server. so A is my proxy server and i made several http proxies using the usable ip's. when i ping website B from server A, the request go through the proxies on the same server then to B, then again through the proxies back to A. since im sending the request on the same server as the proxies, i assume the request from the time it's sent out until it reached the proxies would be instant? as ping from my server to B website is only 1ms, i thought the ping is slightly higher than 1ms but not 90+ms with proxies. am i missing something?

Comment: OK, yes, probably TCP handshake from client to proxy over a high-speed LAN is negligible. The other places delays come in is rule checking in the proxy if you have a large number of rules, or must consult a large set of allowed/blocked sites for example.  Also the type of request can make a difference (e.g. if the request has a body, e.g. POST).

Comment: thank you Adrien. i updated my question with the code (i have more than 10 ip's in my actual code but not listed here). so from the code above, what do you think could be the problem? i tried lots of methods, only changing dns server reduced the latency by about 4ms